# How to do Chat bubble construction in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, messagebox

I have this Android xml layout that looks like this and as you see it has chat bubbles. I wanted to convert it from `LinearLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`
.
This is the `LinearLayout` version and it looks ok

[image]

This is the `ConstraintLayout` version and the chat bubbels don't look so nice.

[image]

I want some help with this bubbles. The arrow as you see is hard to constrain so it looks good. I added one `android.support.constraint.Guideline` to do some constraining but not working.

Here is the `ConstraintLayout` xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end|center_vertical">

    <com.github.curioustechizen.ago.RelativeTimeTextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?AppTheme.ChatBubbleTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/chat_timestamp_text_size"
        tools:text="Just Now"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/message"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_balloon"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="?AppTheme.ChatBubbleTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/chat_message_body_text_size"
        tools:text="This is chat message"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="218dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.859375" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="?AppTheme.ChatBubbleBackGroundColor"
        android:rotation="45"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/tw__composer_logo_blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Maybe there's some library at GitHub that creates bubbles or any idea about this would be great?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it like this, thanks to [ChatMessageView](https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <com.github.curioustechizen.ago.RelativeTimeTextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="?AppTheme.ChatBubbleTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/chat_timestamp_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        tools:text="Just Now"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chatMessageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.88611114"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="319dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/tw__composer_logo_blue" />

    <me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview.ChatMessageView
        android:id="@+id/chatMessageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:cmv_arrowGravity="center"
        app:cmv_arrowPosition="right"
        app:cmv_backgroundColor="?AppTheme.ChatBubbleBackGroundColor"
        app:cmv_backgroundColorPressed="?AppTheme.ChatBubbleBackGroundColorPressed"
        app:cmv_contentPadding="10dp"
        app:cmv_cornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cmv_showArrow="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?AppTheme.ChatBubbleBackGroundColor"/>

    </me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview.ChatMessageView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```